# How to validate the separator / delimiter using an OpenCSV library?

Tags: java, java-8, opencsv

Based on the library [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) I wrote in the following code:

```
@Override
public List<String[]> parseFile() throws IOException, InvalidArgumentException {

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(this.getFile());
    CSVParserBuilder csvParserBuilder = new CSVParserBuilder();
    CSVParser parser = csvParserBuilder.withSeparator(CSV_DEFAULT_SEPARATOR).build();
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(fileReader).withCSVParser(parser).build();

    this.setFileContents(reader.readAll());
    fileReader.close();
    reader.close();

    // validação na mão
    Boolean separatorNotSemicolon = (1 == Arrays.stream(this.getFileContents().get(0)).count());
    if (separatorNotSemicolon) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Separator must be semicolon");
    }

    return this.getFileContents();
}
```

My question is: I looked in the library documentation on how to validate which separator was used to import the file, but the only way I could do it was external.

I already inform the separator that I'm going to use to read the file on the line: `CSVParser parser = csvParserBuilder.withSeparator(CSV_DEFAULT_SEPARATOR).build();`, I was expecting a form of validation from the library if it finds another separator used.

Note: The code is functional, I just wanted to use a validation of the library itself, it would be much more robust than the simple comparison I made.

The line `(1 == Arrays.stream(this.getFileContents().get(0)).count())` indicates that even using the default separator `CSV_DEFAULT_SEPARATOR` the `reader.readAll()` method brought me several lines with only one column and I'm expecting more than 20 columns. A simple but functional comparison.

Any idea to improve the implementation I made at hand?